# How would I test these hypotheses?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, variance, survey

I have some data I've collected. Here are the relevant characteristics:

- **Question**: 'What strategic priorities is your company pursuing over the next 18 to 36 months?'
- Survey takers choose from a number of answers such as 'improving employee engagement' or 'expanding into new markets'.
- **Question**:'What leadership competencies are most needed to successfully achieve your strategic priorities?'
- Survey takers choose from a number of answers such as 'staffing and selection' or 'coaching'.

I want to see whether talent management priorities (competencies) vary by strategic focus. i.e. Do folks with different strategic focuses have different competency priorities? I'm not sure how I would go about testing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want a 'test' to find out the relation between two variable: Talent Management Priority and Strategy Focus. I would recommend **chi-square test**, which is used to test the dependency between two **categorical** variables.

Comment: That's what my initial research has turned up as well. Thanks!